# Replace enum's rawValue property with a custom operator

Tags: ios, swift

Well, to be honest, I don't like calling `rawValue` when accessing `enum` value.
I use `enum` like this almost all the time and I think calling `.rawValue` makes my code less "readable":

```
enum FontSize: CGFloat {
    case Small = 12
    case Normal = 15
    case Large = 18
}
enum Example: String {
    case First = "First"
    case Second = "Second"
}
```

So, I'm trying to define a generic operator for `enum` that "override" `.rawValue`. 
I can do it non-generically.

```
postfix operator .. { }

postfix func .. (lhs: Example) -> String {
    return lhs.rawValue
}

postfix func .. (lhs: FontSize) -> CGFloat {
    return lhs.rawValue
}
```

However, I'm so lazy that I want an universal solution. Writes one, works all.

Can somebody help me with that ? Thank you.

---

**Update**: To people who interested in this question, if you want increase/decrease functions for `enum` like `FontSize` above. Use these:

```
postfix func ++ <T: RawRepresentable, V: FloatingPointType>(lhs: T) -> V {
    return (lhs.rawValue as! V) + 1
}

postfix func -- <T: RawRepresentable, V: FloatingPointType>(lhs: T) -> V {
    return (lhs.rawValue as! V) - 1
}

postfix func ++ <T: RawRepresentable, V: IntegerType>(lhs: T) -> V {
    return (lhs.rawValue as! V) + 1
}

postfix func -- <T: RawRepresentable, V: IntegerType>(lhs: T) -> V {
    return (lhs.rawValue as! V) - 1
}
```

[Gist for future reference here](https://gist.github.com/phamquochoan/2fffda84176c5c8edec0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hei man, you are really lazy! ;-)

```
postfix operator .. { }

postfix func ..<T: RawRepresentable> (lhs: T) -> T.RawValue {
    return lhs.rawValue
}
```

There's a protocol for that :-)

Anyway beware not introducing too much esoteric custom operators ;-)

Comment: Hi Matteo, can you help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224812/override-typecasting-with-custom-operators It's similar with this one :) Thank you.